# perl XML::LibXML parsing issue of invalid char

Tags: xml, perl, char

I am getting the following error while parsing XML with perl XML::LibXML library

file:///C://Users/yhussain/Desktop/DESKTOP/LTE%20TRX/output.xcm:3686518: parser
error : PCDATA invalid Char value 30
     ]▲W☺
                     ^
file:///C://Users/yhussain/Desktop/DESKTOP/LTE%20TRX/output.xcm:3686518: parser
error : PCDATA invalid Char value 1
     ]▲W☺

I used the following command to create a new file removing invalid char

```
perl -CSDA -pe's/[^\x9\xA\xD\x20-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]+//g' input.xml > output.xml
```

If you have better perl command to remove invalid char please let me know.

Comment: That will indeed removed the bad characters, if that's what you want to do.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: The output file I got after the perl command also has invalid char. As in output.xml has invalid char. While parsing output.xml perl script has fatal errors.

Comment: Is the XML encoded using UTF-8?

Comment: This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-t
hread